# What did Kant mean by the "fountain of reason" in the Prolegomena to Any Future Metaphysics?

Tags: kant

What did Kant mean by the "fountain of reason?"

> " … They must wait till those who endeavor to draw from the *fountain of reason* itself have completed their work … " — Kant, Immanuel. Prolegomena to any future metaphysics. Liberal Arts Press, 1985.

[Emphasis via italics is by me and not from the original text.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that ["the fountain (or: wellsprings) of pure reason"](https://books.google.it/books?id=3uH3F0jqDjQC&pg=PA1) must be understood as a figure of speech, in order to contrast Kant intellectual project regarding the foundation of metaphysics with the "traditional philosophical method" of [relying on the authority of ancient philosophers' opinions](https://books.google.it/books?id=hB4XjaGLflMC&pg=PA51).

See [Kant's project in the *Critique of Pure Reason*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant/#KanProThePurRea) :

> The main topic of the *Critique of Pure Reason* is the possibility of metaphysics, understood in a specific way. Kant defines metaphysics in terms of “the cognitions after which reason might strive independently of all experience,” and his goal in the book is to reach a “decision about the possibility or impossibility of a metaphysics in general, and the determination of its sources, as well as its extent and boundaries, all, however, from principles”. Thus metaphysics for Kant concerns a priori knowledge, or knowledge whose justification does not depend on experience; and he associates a priori knowledge with reason. The project of the *Critique* is to examine whether, how, and to what extent human reason is capable of a priori knowledge.

Comment: Please kindly fix the typos and formatting issues in your answer.

Comment: TY, that promptly resolved my misunderstanding! :)